# Video game animation format

Tags: design-patterns, animation, encoding, hex, bytecode

I want to read some video game animations (The game is Bully by Rockstar, similar to the GTA series. It uses the Gamebryo game engine. And was released throughout 2006/2008). The animations are saved with the file extension `.cat`.

I believe the animations are written in bytecode because of the pattern and incrementation of the numbers. Also, many animations are contained in a single .cat file.

This is the entire hex content of an example .cat file which I believe holds four separate animations:

`56 01 00 00 82 00 00 00 1B 01 00 00 82 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 
04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 1C 00 00 00 16 00 
00 00 01 00 3F 00 00 00 1E 00 00 00 01 00 45 00 
00 00 2F 00 00 00 01 00 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
62 84 76 83 81 01 0C 00 00 00 02 00 6C 18 08 D4 
AD 01 00 00 00 00 02 4C 00 00 00 18 00 00 00 00 
00 6C F7 4F 0B AF 00 02 4C 00 00 00 20 00 00 00 
00 00 99 C3 44 56 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 80 BB 
2D 74 00 00 00 00 18 00 00 00 08 00 44 01 00 00 
00 00 00 00 05 00 F7 4F 0B 2F 65 00 00 00 00 00 
C1 00 00 E5 00 00 00 00 00 01 01 00 09 01 00 25 
01 00 00 00 00 45 01 00 00 00 00 60 01 00 00 00 
05 00 6C 5B 6C 6C 41 00 01 65 00 00 00 00 00 85 
00 00 00 80 BF C5 00 16 DD 32 17 05 01 00 00 00 
00 25 01 00 00 00 00 45 01 00 00 00 00 65 01 00 
00 80 BF 85 01 00 00 80 3F A5 01 00 00 80 BF C5 
01 00 00 80 BF E1 01 01 E8 01 00 46 5F 43 6F 6E 
73 74 61 6E 74 69 6E 65 47 72 65 65 74 69 6E 67 
00 6D 69 73 73 69 6F 6E 00 46 5F 45 75 6E 69 63 
65 57 61 6E 74 47 69 66 74 00 47 4E 5F 47 52 45 
45 4B 42 4F 59 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00`

Which translates into strings as:

> /*000:*/
>   "V\x01\x00\x00\x82\x00\x00\x00\x1B\x01\x00\x00\x82\x00\x00\x00"

```
    /*010:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00"
    /*020:*/ "\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x1C\x00\x00\x00\x16\x00"
    /*030:*/ "\x00\x00\x01\x00\?\x00\x00\x00\x1E\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00" "E\x00"
    /*040:*/ "\x00\x00/\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\b\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*050:*/ "b\x84v\x83\x81\x01\f\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00l\x18\b\xD4"
    /*060:*/ "\xAD\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02L\x00\x00\x00\x18\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*070:*/ "\x00l\xF7O\v\xAF\x00\x02L\x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00"
    /*080:*/ "\x00\x00\x99\xC3" "DV\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\xBB"
    /*090:*/ "-t\x00\x00\x00\x00\x18\x00\x00\x00\b\x00" "D\x01\x00\x00"
    /*0A0:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\xF7O\v/e\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*0B0:*/ "\xC1\x00\x00\xE5\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x01\x00\t\x01\x00%"
    /*0C0:*/ "\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00" "E\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00``\x01\x00\x00\x00"
    /*0D0:*/ "\x05\x00l[llA\x00\x01" "e\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x85"
    /*0E0:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x80\xBF\xC5\x00\x16\xDD" "2\x17\x05\x01\x00\x00\x00"
    /*0F0:*/ "\x00%\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00" "E\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00" "e\x01\x00"
    /*100:*/ "\x00\x80\xBF\x85\x01\x00\x00\x80\?\xA5\x01\x00\x00\x80\xBF\xC5"
    /*110:*/ "\x01\x00\x00\x80\xBF\xE1\x01\x01\xE8\x01\x00" "F_Con"
    /*120:*/ "stantineGreeting"
    /*130:*/ "\x00mission\x00" "F_Eunic"
    /*140:*/ "eWantGift\x00GN_GRE"
    /*150:*/ "EKBOY\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*160:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*170:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*180:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*190:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*1A0:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*1B0:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*1C0:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*1D0:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*1E0:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*1F0:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*200:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*210:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*220:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*230:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*240:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*250:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*260:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*270:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*280:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*290:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*2A0:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*2B0:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*2C0:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*2D0:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*2E0:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*2F0:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*300:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*310:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*320:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*330:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*340:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*350:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*360:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*370:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*380:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*390:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*3A0:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*3B0:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*3C0:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*3D0:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*3E0:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*3F0:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*400:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*410:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*420:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*430:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*440:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*450:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*460:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*470:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*480:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*490:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*4A0:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*4B0:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*4C0:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*4D0:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*4E0:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*4F0:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*500:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*510:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*520:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*530:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*540:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*550:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*560:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*570:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*580:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*590:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*5A0:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*5B0:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*5C0:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*5D0:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*5E0:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*5F0:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*600:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*610:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*620:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*630:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*640:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*650:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*660:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*670:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*680:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*690:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*6A0:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*6B0:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*6C0:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*6D0:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*6E0:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*6F0:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*700:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*710:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*720:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*730:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*740:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*750:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*760:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*770:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*780:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*790:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*7A0:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*7B0:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*7C0:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*7D0:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*7E0:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
    /*7F0:*/ "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"`
```

Also translates into unsigned words as:

> ```
>     /*000:*/   342,     0,   130,     0,   283,     0,   130,     0, 
>     /*010:*/     0,     0,     2,     0,     0,     0,     2,     0, 
>     /*020:*/     4,     0,     0,     0,     1,    28,     0,    22, 
>     /*030:*/     0,     1,    63,     0,    30,     0,     1,    69,
> ```

```
    /*040:*/     0,    47,     0,     1,     8,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*050:*/ 33890, 33654,   385,    12,     0,     2,  6252, 54280, 
    /*060:*/   429,     0,     0, 19458,     0,  6144,     0,     0, 
    /*070:*/ 27648, 20471, 44811,   512,    76,     0,    32,     0, 
    /*080:*/     0, 50073, 22084,     0,     0,     0,     0, 48000, 
    /*090:*/ 29741,     0,     0,    24,     0,     8,   324,     0, 
    /*0A0:*/     0,     0,     5, 20471, 12043,   101,     0,     0, 
    /*0B0:*/   193, 58624,     0,     0,   256,     1,   265,  9472, 
    /*0C0:*/     1,     0, 17664,     1,     0, 24576,     1,     0, 
    /*0D0:*/     5, 23404, 27756,    65, 25857,     0,     0, 34048, 
    /*0E0:*/     0, 32768, 50623,  5632, 13021,  1303,     1,     0, 
    /*0F0:*/  9472,     1,     0, 17664,     1,     0, 25856,     1, 
    /*100:*/ 32768, 34239,     1, 32768, 42303,     1, 32768, 50623, 
    /*110:*/     1, 32768, 57791,   257,   488, 17920, 17247, 28271, 
    /*120:*/ 29811, 28257, 26996, 25966, 29255, 25957, 26996, 26478, 
    /*130:*/ 27904, 29545, 26995, 28271, 17920, 17759, 28277, 25449, 
    /*140:*/ 22373, 28257, 18292, 26217,   116, 20039, 18271, 17746, 
    /*150:*/ 19269, 20290,    89,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*160:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*170:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*180:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*190:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*1A0:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*1B0:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*1C0:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*1D0:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*1E0:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*1F0:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*200:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*210:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*220:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*230:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*240:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*250:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*260:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*270:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*280:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*290:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*2A0:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*2B0:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*2C0:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*2D0:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*2E0:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*2F0:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*300:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*310:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*320:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*330:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*340:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*350:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*360:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*370:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*380:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*390:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*3A0:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*3B0:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*3C0:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*3D0:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*3E0:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*3F0:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*400:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*410:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*420:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*430:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*440:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*450:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*460:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*470:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*480:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*490:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*4A0:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*4B0:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*4C0:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*4D0:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*4E0:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*4F0:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*500:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*510:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*520:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*530:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*540:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*550:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*560:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*570:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*580:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*590:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*5A0:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*5B0:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*5C0:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*5D0:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*5E0:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*5F0:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*600:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*610:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*620:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*630:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*640:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*650:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*660:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*670:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*680:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*690:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*6A0:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*6B0:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*6C0:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*6D0:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*6E0:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*6F0:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*700:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*710:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*720:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*730:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*740:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*750:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*760:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*770:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*780:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*790:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*7A0:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*7B0:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*7C0:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*7D0:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*7E0:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 
    /*7F0:*/     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, `
```

Starting with value 6 of line 110 until line 150 is valid ASCII

1. In what way are video game animations typically saved? (For example, object point identifier/xyz coordinates/time frame)
2. Any special encodings?
3. Are you familiar with the format of this code or any traits in it?
4. Provide a link to a better place for these questions